# sending data from edit text with single button

Tags: android, json

![here there are 3 edit text box. where i am using json to check the login id and password details and another text box is for the selection of the server address. the only criteria is that all these should be done with a single button ie the login button.

can any one help me with the code][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH9Yf.png)
  the code is as follows

```
package com.example.catxam;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import com.example.catxam.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Login extends Activity {

private EditText inputUserid, inputPassword, server;
TextView forgotPassword;
private Button b1;
public String serve;


// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String Flag = "flag";


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    inputUserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username_edit);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User_password);
    server = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverSelection);

    forgotPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPassword);
    forgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent passForget = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ForgotPassword.class);
            startActivity(passForget);
        }
    });
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton); // login button


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

                new CreateNewUser().execute();
                new SelectServerAddress().execute();
            }
    });
}

// this class is for selection of the server address
    class SelectServerAddress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            return null;


        }

    }

    // this class is for the checking of the user login and password 
    //i.e. of first login and the next consecutive logins
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Checking..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Checking creditenials
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

String user = inputUserid.getText().toString();
String pswrd = inputPassword.getText().toString();


//if (serve == "")
    //{

        //serve = "192.168.0.101/gly_prov_V1";
    //}
//else
//{
    //serve = "glydenlewis.esy.es";
//}

// URL to check username & password
final String url_check_user = "http://" + serve +"/gly_prov_V1/android_check.php";  

// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", user));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("psd", pswrd));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server",serve));


// getting JSON Object
// Note that create product url accepts POST method
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user,
        "POST", params);

// check log cat from response
Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

// check for success tag
try {
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    int flag_ck = json.getInt(Flag);
    if (success == 1) {
        if (flag_ck == 0)
        {
            //First Time Login By User
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateDetails.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();   // closing this screen  
        }
        else 
        {
        // successfully login
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();   // closing this screen
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;

    }

}

   }
```

Comment: what is the problem? why you do nothing in `SelectServerAddress`?

Comment: i tried doing that but its showing force close. so i removed the code.

Comment: If you want to execute one task before another, all you have to do is to create and execute the second task inside the callback method onPostExecute

Comment: you try doing what? first tell us what is your problem, then what you want exactly

Comment: problem is that i want to take the server address from the user and pass it to serve for further verification of login id and password on the server.

Comment: can u please provide me with the code....

Comment: if you want run two two task, create and execute the second task inside `onPostExecute` of first task

Answer (score 0):

You can execute tasks in serial manner. Take the output of first task as input to the second task.

But you have to implement a cancel mechanism if the activity is destroyed while your tasks is actually running. a simple approach is to make tasks references as a class member and cancel it when activity's onStop() method is called.

```
    class static SelectServerAddress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

         return getAddress(urls[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String serverAddress) {

         // Call login service
         mLoginTask = new CreateNewUser(serverAddress);
         mLoginTask.execute();

    }


}
```

Edit:

Update button click listener code to this:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

            new SelectServerAdress().execute();

        }
});
```

Then update SelectServerAdress class and add this method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String serverAddress) {
    serve = serverAddress;
    new SelectServerAddress().execute();
}
```

Comment: still not able to perform the task. please provide code with respect to the code which i have shown. Note: i am a newbie.

Comment: I have updated the code. You should implement SelectServerAdress and return the address